# PHP4 problems for Ajax, json_encode and database

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, php4

I have my company project which they require PHP4 development.Please check the complete code. It should display list of mobile brands and price and should filter according to multiple checkbox. As i have to work in PHP4 i dont know what mistake i am doing.Its not displaying the information from database.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>AJAX filter demo</title>
        <style>
          body {
            padding: 10px;
          }

          h1 {
              margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
              color: #343434;
              font-weight: normal;
              font-family: 'Ultra', sans-serif;   
              font-size: 36px;
              line-height: 42px;
              text-transform: uppercase;
              text-shadow: 0 2px white, 0 3px #777;
          }

          h2 {
              margin: 1em 0 0.3em 0;
              color: #343434;
              font-weight: normal;
              font-size: 30px;
              line-height: 40px;
              font-family: 'Orienta', sans-serif;
          }

          #phones {
            font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            background: #fff;
            margin: 15px 25px 0 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            text-align: center;
            float: left;
            width: 300px;
          }

          #phones th {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #039;
            padding: 10px 8px;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #6678b1;
          }

          #phones td {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            color: #669;
            padding: 8px 10px;
          }

          #phones tbody tr:hover td {
            color: #009;
          }

          #filter {
            float:left;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body> 
        <h1>Phones database</h1>

        <table id="phones">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Brand</th>
              <th>Model</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <div id="filter">
          <h2>Filter options</h2>
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Samsung" checked>
            <label for="Samsung">Samsung</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="iPhone" checked>
            <label for="iPhone">iPhone</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="HTC" checked>
            <label for="HTC">HTC</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="LG" checked>
            <label for="LG">LG</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Nokia" checked>
            <label for="Nokia">Nokia</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
        <script>
          function makeTable(data){
            console.log(data);
           var tbl_body = "";
              $.each(data, function() {
                var tbl_row = "";
                $.each(this, function(k , v) {
                  tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
                })
                tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
              })

            return tbl_body;
          }

          function getPhoneFilterOptions(){
            var opts = [];
            $checkboxes.each(function(){
              if(this.checked){
                opts.push(this.id);
              }
            });

            return opts;
          }

          function updatePhones(opts){
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "submit.php",
              dataType : 'json',
              cache: false,
              data: {filterOpts: opts},
              success: function(records){
                $('#phones tbody').html(makeTable(records));
              }
            });
          }

          var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
          $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
            var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
            updatePhones(opts);
          });

          $checkboxes.trigger("change");
        </script> 
      </body> 
    </html>
```

submit.php

```
<?php 
require 'Database.php';
#### TEMP SET NAMES FÜR UTF8 ###################################################
require_once('Json.php');

  $opts = $_POST['filterOpts'];
  foreach ($opts as &$opt) {
      $opt = sprintf("'%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($opt));
  }
  $query = sprintf(
      "SELECT mobile_phone.id, name, model, price
       FROM mobile_phone
       INNER JOIN brand ON brand_id = brand.id
       WHERE name IN (%s)",
      join(',', $opts)
  );

  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $data   = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $data[] = $row;
  }

  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Json
[enter link description here](http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/JSON.phps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_encode` OR `json_decode` functions are not included in PHP4, please use PHP4 json manipulation library.

PS: you have included `Json.php`, the library have not `json_*` functions, the `Json.php` file have `Services_JSON` class, please use this way

```
$jsonObj = new Services_JSON();
echo $jsonObj->encode($data);
```

Comment: Hi, you mean i should not include Json.php file and use above line of code in submit.php file ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi,I tried removing Json.php file and including the above line of code u gave me but still not getting data..

Comment: @user3659737 `Json.php` file have JSON manipulation methods e.g **encode**, **decode**, please create object of `Services_JSON` class and call method by object., i have mentioned sample code in bottom

Comment: @user3659737 what you got ajax response, can you please share with me?

Comment: Hi,I am getting checkboxes filter options and just a table without any data from the database.Only the problem is i am not getting data from database.Otherwise i think my checkbox will filter the data once i get the data from database.

Comment: ok, share `firebug` ajax request/response, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: Hi,u can see demo of this example here http://hibbard.eu/blog/pages/phones_new/  and the complete example here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?1184333-Use-AJAX-to-filter-MySQL-results-with-multiple-checkbox-option                         I am trying to run this code and if it works then i want to make changes in that.

Comment: Hi Girish,can u please tell me how to share firebug demo?

Comment: Hi Girish please do u know solution for this?

Comment: OK, i checked `http://hibbard.eu/blog/pages/phones_new/` link, the site server have PHP5.

Comment: yes but for my project i have to work on PHP4 thats why i am facing such problems and did not find a solution for this problem as i did not use PHP4 before.